# Сплеш-layout и загрузка приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть два relativeLayout

1. splashRelativeLayout
2. playzoneRelativeLayout

Написал такой код, чтобы splashRelativeLayout выходил как сплэш в начале загрузки приложения на 5 секунд.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    splashRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playzoneRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            splashRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            playzoneRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    },5000);
}
```

Но, перед тем как splashRelativeLayout появится на экране программа показывает белое окошко - ждет пока загрузится все приложение и только потом показывает splashRelativeLayout.
Как сделать так, чтобы приложение сразу первым делом показал splashRelativeLayout, а потом только не спеша загружал все остальные лайоуты.

Comment: Правильная [реализация сплэш-скрина](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте отдельную SplashActivity, которая будет `LAUNCHER` в манифесте:

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Показывайте в ней свой сплэш-лэйаут:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashRelativeLayout);
}
```

Ну и в `onResume` пропишите свой хэндлер с задержкой показа:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // запустите основную активити после задержки
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();

            // можно добавить какую-либо анимацию при закрытии сплэш - к примеру, исчезновение
            SplashActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_activity, R.anim.fade_out_activity);
        }
    },5000);
}
```

res/anim/fade_in_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

res/anim/fade_out_activity.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Comment: А  removeCallback для Handler вызывать не надо? Не будет проблем с утечкой памяти? После того как хэндлер отобразить MainActivity, то хэндлер автоматом же умрет?

Comment: @androman проблем не будет.

Comment: проблемы будут, поэтому вызывайте

Comment: @tim_taller, активность с хэндлером умрет послe `finish`

Comment: Т.е в конце каждого хэндлера лучше вызывать finish, чтобы хэндлер умер наверняка?

Comment: @androman в конкретном примере в идеальном случае @Flippy прав - через 5сек `SplashActivity` задестроится и хендлер с ним же. но в случае, если вдруг до окончания этих 5 сек приложение свернут/откроют другое приложение, то хендлер отработает и из свернутого состояния выскочит `MainActivity`, что с т.з. пользователя будет неприятным поведением. в следствии этого хендлер лучше делать через переменную, которую ремувить по надобности